# How can I get randomized grid search to be more verbose? (seems stopped, but can't diagnose)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation, grid-search

I'm running a relatively large job, which involves doing a randomized grid search on a dataset, which (with a small n_iter_search) already takes a long time.

I'm running it on a 64 core machine, and for about 2 hours it kept 2000 threads active working on the first folds. It then stopped reporting completely into the stdout. It's last report was: 
`[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   4 out of  60 | elapsed: 84.7min remaining: 1185.8min`

I've noticed on htop that almost all cores are at 0%, which would not happen when training random forests. No feedback or errors from the program, if it weren't for htop I would assume it is still training. This has happened before, so it is a recurring problem. The machine is perfectly responsive and the process seems alive.

I already have verbose = 10. Any thoughts on how I can diagnose what it going on inside the RandomizedSearchCV?

The grid search I'm doing:

> rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
>
> param_grid = {
>       'n_estimators': sp_randint(100, 5000),
>       'max_features' : ['auto', None],
>       'min_samples_split' : sp_randint(2, 6)
>   }
>
> n_iter_search = 20
>
> CV_rfc = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rfc, param_distributions=param_grid, n_iter = n_iter_search, verbose = 10,n_jobs = -1)

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but you probably shouldn't grid search n_estimators: more is always better. So if 100 estimators is an acceptable value for you I'd suggest to stick with it for the search process. Otherwise sampled parameters with higher n_estimators will get an unfair advantage.

Comment: Very fair point,  I should have used learning curves for that. Might (curiously) solve the problem, should  the underlying issue be some of the cores taking up too much memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first step, adding the `verbose` parameter to the `RandomForestClassifier` as well could let you see if the search is really stuck. It will display progress in fitting the trees (`building tree 88 out of 100` ...).

I don't really know why your search got stuck, but thinking about it removing the search on `n_estimators` should enable you to grid search the entire space of parameters you specified here in just 8 iterations.